# function with complex roots and two complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following equation:
$$ \lambda^2 = z^2 + i\frac{1}{x}$$ .
where $\lambda, z$ and $x$ are complex numbers.

Is it possible to write $\lambda$ as a complex function with variables $z$ and $x$ and to specify its domain? I am not quite sure how to handle the complex root and the two different complex numbers $z$ and $x$.

Comment: It doesn't really matter much that there are two variables. Consider the simpler question of if $\mu^2=z$ means $\mu$ can be written as a function of $z$. The thing to look up is "branch cut." Where does this question come from? It sounds like you could use help with some other math that led to this question.

Comment: So then my function would be $\lambda(z,x)=\sqrt{z^2+\frac{1}{x}}$ with the branch cut $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: You can do that if you want.

Comment: I do have a complicated equation which i would like to show to be holomorphic .. $ F(x,z,\lambda)=\frac{\left( z-\lambda\right) +(z+\lambda) e^{i2\lambda x} }{(z+\lambda)+(z-\lambda)e^{i2\lambda x} } +e^{-2iz \ell}$. ($\ell$ is a real constant). And $\lambda$ is defined over the equation above $\lambda^2=z^2+\frac{1}{x}$.